# Python: Redefining function from within the function

Tags: python

I have some expensive function f(x) that I want to only calculate once, but is called rather frequently. In essence, the first time the function is called, it should compute a whole bunch of values for a range of x since it will be integrated over anyway and then interpolate that one with splines, and cache the coefficients somehow, possibly in a file for further use.

My idea was to do something like the following, since it would be pretty easy to implement. First time the function is called, it does something, then redefines itself, then does something else from then on. However, it does not work as expected and might in general be bad practice.

```
def f():
    def g():
        print(2)
    print(1)
    f = g
f()
f()
```

Expected output:

```
1
2
```

Actual output:

```
1
1
```

Defining g() outside of f() does not help. Why does this not work? Other than that, the only solution I can think of right now is to use some global variable. Or does it make sense to somehow write a class for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is overly complicated. Instead, use memoization:

```
def memoized(f):
    res = []
    def resf():
       if len(res) == 0
           res.append(f())
       return res[0]
    return resf
```

and then simply

```
@memoized
def f():
   # expensive calculation here ...
   return calculated_value
```

In Python 3, you can replace `memoized` with [`functools.lru_cache`](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache).

Comment: +1: [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) and [decoration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Decorators), in Python versions that permit decoration, are the way to go. Canonical example [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize).

Comment: Don't you get a problem with the fact that dict is unhashable?

Comment: @juanchopanza Oops, yes. Deleted arguments, as they are unnecessary in this example anyway.

Comment: @phihag I wish there was a simple in-built solution to memoizing **kwargs!

Comment: @juanchopanza Well, you can always take the items and convert to a `frozenset`, but it breaks down anyway as soon as values in args/kwargs are not hashable.

Comment: Python 3 already has a LRU-Cache decorator: http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache
(just in case you are using it)

Comment: @naeg Thanks! Searched for it, but couldn't find it. Added in the answer.

Comment: @phihag I started a question on caching **kwargs, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407993/how-to-memoize-kwargs

Answer (score 6):

Simply add `global f` at the beginning of the f function, otherwise python creates a local f variable.

Answer (score 3):

Changing f in f's scope doesn't affect outside of function, if you want to change f, you could use global:

```
>>> def f():
...     print(1)
...     global f
...     f=lambda: print(2)
... 
>>> f()
1
>>> f()
2
>>> f()
2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [memoization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization) and [decoration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_syntax_and_semantics#Decorators) to cache the result. See an example [here](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecoratorLibrary#Memoize). A separate question on memoization that might prove useful can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407993/how-to-memoize-kwargs).

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing is the kind of problem caching was invented for. Why not just have a buffer to hold the result; before doing the expensive calculation, check if the buffer is already filled; if so, return the buffered result, otherwise, execute the calculation, fill the buffer, and then return the result. No need to go all fancy with self-modifying code for this.

Comment: He speaketh the truth. Amen (+1).