# How to memoize **kwargs?

Tags: python, memoization

I haven't seen an established way to memoize a function that takes key-word arguments, i.e. something of type

```
def f(*args, **kwargs)
```

since typically a memoizer has a `dict` to cache results for a given set of input parameters, and `kwargs` is a `dict` and hence unhashable. I have tried, following discussions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6401640/python-redefining-function-from-within-the-function/6401683#6401683), using

```
(args, frozenset(kwargs.items()))
```

as key to the cache `dict`, but this only works if the values in `kwargs` are hashable. Furthermore, as pointed out in answers below is that `frozenset` is not an ordered data structure. Therefore this solution might be safer:

```
(args, tuple(sorted(kwargs.items())))
```

But it still cannot cope with un-hashable elements. Another approach I have seen is to use a `string` representation of the `kwargs` in the cache key:

```
(args, str(sorted(kwargs.items())))
```

The only drawback I see with this is the overhead of hashing a potentially very long string. As far as I can see the results should be correct. Can anyone spot any problems with the latter approach? One of the answers below points out that this assumes certain behaviour of the `__str__` or `__repr__` functions for the values of the key-word arguments. This seems like a show-stopper.

Is there another, more established way of achieving memoization that can cope with `**kwargs` and un-hashable argument values?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
key = (args, frozenset(kwargs.items()))
```

This is the "best" you can do without making assumptions about your data.

However it seems conceivable to want to perform memoization on dictionaries (a bit unusual though), you could special-case that if you desired it. For example you could recursively apply `frozenset(---.items())` while copying dictionaries.

---

If you do `sorted`, you could be in a bad situation where you have unorderable keys. For example, "*The subset and equality comparisons do not generalize to a complete ordering function. For example, any two disjoint sets are not equal and are not subsets of each other, so all of the following return False: a<b, a==b, or a>b. Accordingly, sets do not implement the **cmp**() method.*"

```
>>> sorted([frozenset({1,2}), frozenset({1,3})])
[frozenset({1, 2}), frozenset({1, 3})]

>>> sorted([frozenset({1,3}), frozenset({1,2})]) # THE SAME
[frozenset({1, 3}), frozenset({1, 2})] # DIFFERENT SORT RESULT

# sorted(stuff) != sorted(reversed(stuff)), if not strictly totally ordered
```

**edit:** Ignacio says "While you can't use sorted() on arbitrary dicts, kwargs will have str keys." This is entirely correct. Thus this is not an issue for keys, though possibly something to keep in mind for values if you (or unlikely repr) are relying on sorting somehow.

---

Regarding using `str`:

It is the case **most** data will work nicely, but it is possible for an adversary (e.g. in a security-vulnerability context) to craft a collision. It's not easy mind you because most default `repr`s use lots of good grouping and escape. In fact I was not able to find such a collision. But it is possible with sloppy third-party or incomplete `repr` implementations.

---

Also consider the following: If you are storing keys like `((<map object at 0x1377d50>,), frozenset(...))` and `((<list_iterator object at 0x1377dd0>,<list_iterator object at 0x1377dd0>), frozenset(...))`, your cache will grow unboundedly just by calling the same items. (You could perhaps work around this issue with a regex...) And attempting to consume the generators will mess up the semantics of the function you're using. This may be desired behavior though if you wish to memoize on `is`-style equality rather than `==`-style equality.

Also doing something like `str({1:object()})` in the interpreter will return an object at the same location in memory each time! I think this is the garbage collector at work. This would be disastrous, because if you happen to be hashing `<some object at 0x???????>` and you happen to create an object of the same type at the same memory location later on (due to garbage collection), you will get incorrect results from the memoized function. As mentioned, one possibly really hackish workaround is to detect such objects with a regex.

Comment: +1 Very good point, with the second method one is at the mercy of the `__str__` or `__repr__` methods of the data.

Comment: Do you have a feeling as to whether the ordering of `frozenset(kwargs.items())` is deterministic for the same `kwargs`, on the same platform?

Comment: While you can't use `sorted()` on arbitrary dicts, kwargs will have str keys.

Comment: @juanchopanza: a `set` or `frozenset` has no ordering

Comment: Indeed, so that probably rules out the first option. But maybe a `tuple` of sorted `kwargs.items()`...

Comment: @ninjagecko, your answer addresses many important issues, but I think your first statement isn't correct, if one considers `frozenset` order issues. I have expanded my question to reflect some if the information gained from the answers. I haven't selected an answer yet because I'd like to see if someone has a magical solution or if the consensus is that there isn't one.

Comment: @juanchopanza: "*Furthermore, as pointed out in answers below is that frozenset is not an ordered data structure.*" That doesn't mean equality is undefined. I myself brought up the frozenset order issue (not really an issue); I would be aware if I was being inconsistent. =) In fact your suggestion of `tuple(sorted(kwargs.items()))` (which has the minor overhead of sorting) is exactly the reason I was worried and brought up the issue: but as Ignacio rightfully points out the issue won't matter because the keys are always orderable strings. I no longer think the `frozenset` order issues matter.

Comment: @ninjagecko my issue is that the ordering isn't defined, so frozenset(some_sequence) in one place might not be the same as in other place. Unlikely, but if the standard doesn't guarantee ordering then I'd rather not rely on it.

Comment: @ninjagecko I am choosing your answer, since I am now convinced that for kwargs a frozenset is OK.

Comment: `')' expected` on `(args, frozenset(kwargs.items())`, probably wrong in Python 3

Comment: @Gulzar: missing paren typo, not a python3 issue

Answer (score 7):

dicts can be in arbitrary order, so there's no guarantee that the latter will work. Use `sorted(kwargs.items())` to get it sorted by key first.

Comment: +1 very good point! I will correct the question, since it wasn't the main point.

Comment: BTW, would that invalidate the first method using frozenset?

Comment: I don't know the particulars about `frozenset`'s contract, but I believe that it could.

Comment: Memoization typically uses the args as keys to a dict with the results, and `hash(sorted({'key': 'arg'}.items()))` fails
but `hash(frozenset({'key': 'arg'}.items()))` works.

Answer (score 4):

It's similar to what EMS said, but the best way would be:

```
key = cPickle.dumps((*args, **kwargs))
```

I've been doing a lot of research and testing for memorization with decorators, and this is the best method I've found so far.

Answer (score 3):

Here:

```
from functools import wraps

def memoize(fun):
    """A simple memoize decorator for functions supporting positional args."""
    @wraps(fun)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        key = (args, frozenset(sorted(kwargs.items())))
        try:
            return cache[key]
        except KeyError:
            ret = cache[key] = fun(*args, **kwargs)
        return ret
    cache = {}
    return wrapper
```

Tests:

```
import unittest

class TestMemoize(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_it(self):
        @memoize
        def foo(*args, **kwargs):
            "foo docstring"
            calls.append(None)
            return (args, kwargs)

        calls = []
        # no args
        for x in range(2):
            ret = foo()
            expected = ((), {})
            self.assertEqual(ret, expected)
            self.assertEqual(len(calls), 1)
        # with args
        for x in range(2):
            ret = foo(1)
            expected = ((1, ), {})
            self.assertEqual(ret, expected)
            self.assertEqual(len(calls), 2)
        # with args + kwargs
        for x in range(2):
            ret = foo(1, bar=2)
            expected = ((1, ), {'bar': 2})
            self.assertEqual(ret, expected)
            self.assertEqual(len(calls), 3)
        self.assertEqual(foo.__doc__, "foo docstring")

unittest.main()
```

This works as long as you don't pass an unhashable type (e.g. dict) as argument.
I don't have a solution for that but collections.lru_cache() implementation might have.
See _make_key() function here:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578078/

Answer (score 0):

What about `key = pickle.dumps( (args, sorted(kwargs.items()), -1 )`?
This would appear to be a more robust approach than str() or repr().