# How to memoize/hash **kwargs (or dictionaries in general) for use as key

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, keyword-argument

None of the solutions I've seen ([How to memoize **kwargs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6407993/how-to-memoize-kwargs) for instance), seem to make use of `json.dumps(d, sort_keys=True)`. Is there a particular reason that using `frozenset` or tuples is preferred?

Could performance be an issue?

Comment: Well, in general, `json.dumps` can only handle a rather restricted set of kwargs. Also note, in that example, people suggest `pickle.dumps` which is more general.